# Java regex pattern for lists

Tags: java, regex

What Java regex pattern should I use to match lists of positive integers in the notation (e.g. (5, 44, 1, 67, 114))? Each number should be followed by a comma then an arbitrary number of spaces:

```
"(4, 1, 19, 22, 540)"
"(84, 55, 7, 40, 77231, 18, 35, 13)"
"(6,    5794,       81, 2,  334)"
```

Comment: Do you want the list or just the integers?

Comment: There are many online tutorials for performing regex.  In this particular example, the '(' would need to be escaped using a '\' (Which is \\ in java).  followed by a digit '\d' that is repeated one or more times '+' followed by a ','.  This item '[ item contents ]' is repeated 0 or more times * followed by a ' ' repeated 0 or more times *.  Please look into this further and attempt to come up with a regex solution.  If you still have difficulties I'm sure someone can help you further.

Answer (score 0):

You can use classes from java.util.regex package: **Matcher** and **Pattern**. 
The pattern which will suit your expectations is

```
[0-9]+
```

because it takes all of consecutive digits in one sequence.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "(84, 55, 7, 40, 77231, 18, 35, 13)";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    while(m.find())
        System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

then if you want to parse it from String to int you can use:

```
Integer.parseInt(m.group())
```

for more about using Regex in Java you can read [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/).
Hope it helps.